# php send mail script encoding issue on windows

Tags: php, encoding, sendmail

I have problem with non english characters with this e-mail script. If I set the script to send e-mail to my gmail account, I have no problem. However, if I set the script to send email to my domain account and if i open the email with windows live mail or with microsoft outlook then the e-mail is not readable. I must to go to encoding menu, and then select the utf-8, and then i can read the email.

If I open the mail on iMac mail client, i have no problem.

My customer see this as big problem and want me to solve it. Anyone can help?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// send the form to the specify email

// CONFIG VARS
$subject = "mysite.com | contact form";
$to = "myaccount@somemail.com";
$from = 'another@somemail.com';


//data
$msg = "Name: "  .$_POST['namesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Email: "  .$_POST['emailsup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Phone: "  .$_POST['phonesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Message: "  .$_POST['yourtextsup']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this code it will work for me,

```
<?php

$subject = "mysite.com | contact form";
$to = "myaccount@somemail.com";
$from = 'another@somemail.com';

 $msg = '<html>
            <head>
            </head>
                <body>
                <p>
                               Name: ".$_POST['namesup']."<br>
                               Email: ".$_POST['emailsup']."<br>
                               Phone: ".$_POST['phonesup']."<br>
                               Message: ".$_POST['yourtextsup']."<br>
                    </p>
                </body>
        </html>';

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

    mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
?>
```

This line     `$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";` is resolved your issue of like Arabic language or others.

Comment: Hi Advait. I just test the code above, same story. Unreadable characters.

Comment: Can @Zoran give me some sample of text, so i can test & get back to you.

Comment: Μήνυμα Όνομα are some words thar one may enter

Comment: point is to open the message in microsoft outlook and to see those words, and not unreadable characters

Comment: @zoran you check that which i have edited,if you find any problem let me know i get back to you after sometime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22906/discussion-between-zoran-and-advait-amin)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making sure your message is valid HTML, including the `<html>` and `<head>` tags, and also make sure you include the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />` tag. So:

```
//data
$msg = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>';
$msg .= "Name: "  .$_POST['namesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Email: "  .$_POST['emailsup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Phone: "  .$_POST['phonesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Message: "  .$_POST['yourtextsup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: I will try that right now Gareth and I will let you know if it works

Comment: nope. same result. i get unreadable characters + html tags inside.

Comment: Are you sure the page that collects the post variables is encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your scripts charset to:

```
<?php
// send the form to the specify email

// CONFIG VARS
$subject = "mysite.com | contact form";
$to = "myaccount@somemail.com";
$from = 'another@somemail.com';


//data
$msg = "Name: "  .$_POST['namesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Email: "  .$_POST['emailsup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Phone: "  .$_POST['phonesup']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "Message: "  .$_POST['yourtextsup']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: i tried that with iso-8859-7 which is what I need, (greek encoding) and it didn't worked.